# Duplicate alternate columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a table created by joining a table to itself.

```
SELECT a.id id1, b.id id2, ST_Distance(a.geom, b.geom) dist
FROM yy_cluster_1 a, yy_cluster_1 b 
WHERE ST_DWithin(a.geom, b.geom, 12) AND a.id <> b.id
ORDER BY a.id, b.id
```

This results in a table like the one below on the left. I am trying to number rows to produce the result on the right

[image]

For the life of me I cannot think how to do this, let alone efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dense_rank()` along with `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
SELECT 
    a.id id1, 
    b.id id2, 
    ST_Distance(a.geom, b.geom) dist,
    dense_rank() over(order by least(a.id, b.id), greatest(a.id, b.id)) new_id
FROM 
    yy_cluster_1 a
    INNER JOIN yy_cluster_1 b ON ST_DWithin(a.geom, b.geom, 12) AND a.id <> b.id
ORDER BY a.id, b.id
```

Note that I changed your query so it performs an explicit `join` instead of an old-school implicit join.

Comment: Awesome, thanks... I'll accept answer after the minimum time I can accept passes.